# Postman can't reach localhost

Tags: proxy, postman

I am in a corporate env so I have to use a proxy to reach servers. This works well in postman and in browsers. What I can't reach is localhost in postman but I can reach localhost in the browser.

I am running Postman for Linux Version 6.0.9. I have tried reaching localhost:9082/rest/myapi.... and 127.0.0.1:9082/rest/myapi with both global proxy and system proxy turned on and with either turned on and with non turned on. In all cases I am not able to reach localhost.

What I get as an response is an error page from the proxy server! Someway the call gets out on the network instead of being kept on my machine.

The postman console:

My request headers are:

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →986
Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Pragma →no-cache
Proxy-Connection →Keep-Alive
```

My response headers are:

```
cache-control:"no-cache"
pragma:"no-cache"
content-type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
proxy-connection:"Keep-Alive"
connection:"Keep-Alive"
content-length:"986"
```

My response body is an html page.

How can I make a call to `localhost` work with postman?

Comment: It seems this has been solved in v.7.0.9. For versions before that,  [Nayak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54288710/5122657) below worked for me.

Comment: Postman 7.2.1 was working then started getting a 'Could not get any response' error connecting to localhost. Turned off 'Use System Proxy' in settings, and it started working again. We're not using a proxy as far as I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a temporary solution:

In terminal, go to the directory where postman is installed and add:

```
machine@dev:~/Documents/Postman$ export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1
machine@dev:~/Documents/Postman$ ./Postman
```

This will make calls to localhost work.

I found a similar problem on Windows machines [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3942)

Answer (score 164):

I was having similar issue with HTTP calls to local ASP.NET Core Web API apps. Changing the proxy settings didn't fix it for me.

Finally fixed it by turning off **File > Settings > General > SSL Certificate Verification**

Comment: Postman will take the proxy settings from some environment variables (http_proxy, HTTPS_PROXY, etc) even if they are turned off from the UI

Comment: This will work, but [Peter Matisko's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853979/336648) is probably both simpler and better, even if it has racked up significantly fewer votes so far; it avoids messing with / disabling SSL verification.

Answer (score 46):

I have the same issue. What works for me is:

Open File -> Settings -> Proxy

Then, enable proxy and put 127.0.0.1 : 80, if your web server runs on 80.

In the git thread, they say it is a known issue, so hopefully it will get resolved soon.

Comment: This solution seems by far to be the easiest way around this problem. No need to mess with environment variables, no need to open possible security holes.

Comment: Worked for me, but I wish I understood why. I noticed when I `ping localhost`, I get the IPv6 address `::1` not the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1`. Possibly related?

Comment: @TBirkulosis I am not sure, if the behaviour without the proxy isn't actually a bug. Postman probably reaches to a wrong place. I haven't found a proper answer either.

Answer (score 20):

I solved this by Turning off System proxy of Postman.

Open **File -> Settings -> Proxy**

[image: Postman]

Then Turn off **Use System Proxy**

Comment: How frustrating when I've tried every other answer up to this point before finding the one that works. It seems there's any number of ways for it not to work with very little indication of what the problem is.

Comment: @DaveDev closest thing I can give for you that it should be something with corporate proxies. You might need some networking wisdom too to find this out. But my friend I have backlogs to finish before I sleep :)

Answer (score 12):

@Menuka Ishan Answer is correct. But in mac only if we change the turn off proxy won't work. You need to turn off the SSL Certificate verification also you need to disable.

[image: Open Setting -> General -> SSL Certificate verification -> OFF]

Comment: Please do not switch off SSL verification. This could be potentially a huge security risk.

Comment: @Dharman. But if i didn't turn off SSL verification post man is not working. There is any other way?

Comment: The .NET Core Web API tutorial walks you thru turning off this option also: See => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#install-postman
It is helpful for localhost development

Answer (score 7):

The problem mentioned as an issue [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4459). You should just write a simple batch file like this:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=
set http_proxy=
set HTTPS_PROXY=
set https_proxy=
START %LOCALAPPDATA%\Postman\Update.exe --processStart "Postman.exe"
```

open a simple text file, save this as a ".bat" file, and just run it!

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue, but the trick was I implemented both the methods that were stated earlier in the stack.
First I turned **off** the **postman proxy** as shown in below image.

**Click Settings -> Proxy**

[image]

And then turned **off** the **SSL certificate verification** check button.

**Click Settings -> General**

[image]

And then tried to hit my local server and finally it worked.

Answer (score 3):

While attempting to Get https://localhost:5001/WeatherForecast via PostMan while developing a basic .NET Core (3.1) Web API (on Ubuntu Linux)
I got the error:

> Could not get any response There was an error connecting to
>   https://localhost:5001/WeatherForecast.

I didn't notice the actual solution in the things to try at first, but if you check the highlighted text in the image you will see it.

[image: postman error]

You can see that the option is turned on in PostMan by default:

[image: PostMan Settings]

I turned the **SSL Certificate Verification** off and tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you are under corporate proxy and you are deploying your webapplication in localhost then no need to set proxy configuration like

```
http://username:password@corporateProxyServer:ServerPort in postman (Global Proxy Configuration).
```

As the app is deployed in local machine just use the localhost configuration in setting -> Global Proxy Configuration as :

```
 proxy server : 127.0.0.1
 port : 8300 (this is the port where the web application is running )
```

Comment: This one worked for me. But it seems the problem has been solved in v7.0.9

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that i was setting an invalid Header token and it gave me the error

> Error: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["Accept "]
>   Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers

Just check your Headers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another potential answer to this for people to check after they've tried the other ideas here.

I was able to solve my own problem by checking the Postman console (View -> Show Postman Console) and then examining the error from the request (in my case it was because I had a newline character on an auth token).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to precede the `localhost` with `https://`

Answer (score 0):

These steps solved this issue after 1 whole day struggle:
1) HTTP_PROXY= proxy.company.com:port
   HTTPS_PROXY=proxy.company.com:port
 to user variables, not to System variables. Make sure the the case is all cap.
2) Updating newtwork driver, and turning on Windows Defender......Make sure you don't see no reds in here.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make any calls from postman to docker container running Couchbase Server. Very frustrating. Turns out I had proxy setting configured to some aws instance which has been long deleted.

Goto setting and remove the proxy setting and it worked like a charm on localhost/127.0.0.1/mac laptop eno IP addr or 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using `django-tenants` and had to add the domain for the tenant in `etc/hosts` to get it working on localhosts. My entry for `127.0.0.1` now looks like

`127.0.0.1       localhost test.localhost`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was forgetting to select Environment. From the drop down where you see **No Environment** in the image, select the name of your environment.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Menuka Ishan's solution above saved my hours of pain! I left the `Global Proxy Configuration` switched `ON` and changed the `Proxy Server` to `127.0.0.1`. Switched `OFF` the `Use System Proxy`. I already had the entry `127.0.0.1       localhost` in my hosts file under the path `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have active proxy in your system then make sure **Global Proxy Configuration** and **Use System Proxy** are **turned off**. To do this go to Postman preferences > Proxy. You can also try sending a request in postman without typing localhost (e.g. *:8080/send*)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think i also found a perfect fix. 
First you turn on global proxy configurations, add your local machine Ip which is 127.0.0.1,then also add localhost in the bypass. 
Also turn off SSL verification.
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I disable the parameter host in the header.

[HOST Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BawTW.png)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for a **solution to WooCommerce local install**, here are the steps to make this work:

1. Go to Wordpress Admin > WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced
2. Create new API key, give it a name
3. Copy the Consumer Key & Consumer Secret to
   your text editor
4. Open Postman
5. Create new connection Set the URL for
   testing (GET) : http://mylocalsite/wp-json/wc/v3/orders (change
   "mylocalsite" to yours)
6. Click on Authorization tab
7. Now here is the main change: Although in WC Rest docs, it says to use the "Basic Auth" - **IT WILL NOT WORK**. Since usually your localhost is HTTP
   and not HTTPS. So "Basic Auth" is not relevant in our case.
8. You will need to change the Authorization to OAuth 1.0
9. Set Consumer Key & Consumer Secret respectively as it shows in Woocommerce
10. Click "Send" - it should work now

If still you have problems, try one by one the following:

1. File > Settings > Turn off SSL Verification
2. File > Settings > Turn off "Automatically follow redirects"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that couldn't get response from localhost. I downloaded postman to my computer desktop version then I could get back response.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you call a non-existent route.  For example, you try to get `/api/nonexistant` but it's actually `/api/righthere`

Slaps Head