# Get request from Postman does't work in ASP.NET controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, postman, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a new API controller to the Sample Project generated by VS 2019. This is the most simple case I could find with tutorials. There is nothing fancy or complicated. I started the project with React and Redux addons.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("mock")]
    public ActionResult<User> GetUser()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.Id = "adasds";
        user.Password = "adadasd";
        user.Email = "adasd@sads.com";

        return user;
    }
}
```

'https://localhost:44338/api/user' works fine with Chrome but does't in Postman. I need to make a post resquest also.

I'm coming from Spring and Java, so I'm completely lost. I suspect the port might be wrong but I can't find a way to configure it.

Comment: What's happening in the console? Open the Developer tools, check the console, then check the network. To open the developer tool, press Ctrl+Shift+I in your chrome (just in case you didn't know)

Comment: what console? how do I check the network?

Comment: When opening the Developer tool, there's a tab at the top. Which contains some tabs as Elements, Console, Source, Network, Performance...

Comment: Web browser, Chrome, Firefox, etc... Lunch your application and enter the route of the API in your browser

Comment: So, what should I see there? This is a API and I'm trying to access from Postman.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192086/discussion-between-mohamad-mousheimish-and-thadeu-antonio-ferreira-melo).

Comment: As you wish, the latest thing i can say to you. First replace `api/[controller]` with `api/User`. Second try to remove `[ApiController]`. It happened with me one time. And best of luck.

Comment: You've probably used a wrong tag. Looks to me like you're actually using ASP.NET Core, not MVC 4.

Comment: @Knelis yep, I'm trying to implement this tutorial https://medium.com/@geekrodion/blog-with-asp-net-core-and-react-redux-part-1-authentication-94b11b1a1bc4

The point is that I'm still can't do a simple GET request, no matter how many controllers I add to the project.

Comment: I found the real problem and solution in this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130558/postman-cant-reach-localhost