# Flask API can receive posts from AJAX but not Postman

Tags: json, ajax, http, flask, postman

We have a Flask API that talks to multiple sources, a web app, and an external source. In the web app, we use AJAX to send a JSON post to the API which is successful. From an external source, whether it's postman or the VaRest Unreal Engine plugin, we get a 400 Error: Bad Request even though we use the correct content-type header.

If anyone can help us figure out why the posts we are sending aren't properly identified we would really appreciate it.

Thanks

This is the JS code from our web app, used to create the JSON which is sent through AJAX (this is the successful code)

```
var but1 = document.getElementById('but1');
  const data1 = {
    number: 1 ,
    type: 1 ,
    value: 100
  }
  but1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    $.post(url, data1);
    });
```

This is a post route in our python API that takes in the input and saves it to a file we have

```
@app.route('/button', methods=['POST'])
def button():
   buttonLog = open("buttonLog.txt", "w")
   buttonLog.write(request.form['number'])
   buttonLog.close()
   typeOf = int(request.form['type'])
   value = int(request.form['value'])
   return "success"
```

Here is our JSON post, with headers

[Postman JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWGEk.png)

[Postman Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZaXw.png)

The AJAX post works as intended, but the postman post/Unreal engine post are not being seen as "posts" to the API.

Comment: Are you working in localhost?

Comment: Yes, it's just over a local network

Comment: Because it's in localhost I'd recommend watching this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130558/postman-cant-reach-localhost