# " Could not send request " error in Postman Web version

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, postman

I am using postman web version.
I sent request using POST on `url = localhost:3000/students`
But it is giving error :

```
Could not send request
Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost. Select a different agent.
```

Please help what to do :(

Comment: Hi, Do this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49130558/postman-cant-reach-localhost

Comment: I think it's a new restriction of Postman for make people use the desktop version. In the past it has worked, for sure.

Comment: Don't you have the solution?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Postman Website **cannot** send a request to your computer's localhost. It first *needs* to connect to your PC with the Postman desktop client. You can download it [here](https://www.postman.com/downloads/). Run it, then go to the Postman workspace in your browser -> send the request and it will work.

Answer (score 8):

i got same issue, postman web version cannot send request to localhost.
.
So i'm just use desktop version of postman and it works

Answer (score 2):

The Error is pretty much clear here.
`Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost. Select a different agent.`

Postman web version cannot able to send requests to the server that runs on your local PC(localhost). In order to send a request to the localhost URL, you need to install Postman desktop client.

Comment: but why, is the question?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue recently. Just use the postman desktop app and after sign in, post/get etc. requests can be executed without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, download the postman PC agent, and run it. Once you get the error, down there postman provides additional details on downloading pc agent and you will be good.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must use Postman Agent to make requests to your localhost. This is the link: https://www.postman.com/downloads/postman-agent/

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution that you can do, just install the postman agent, and after that install, it, then test your Rest API in your postman web version it will work properly.
postman agent: https://dl-agent.pstmn.io/download/latest/win64

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you try to connect to your computer's local host while sending the request through the Postman website. So, try to download ***Postman Desktop Client*** to send request locally to your computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The funny thing is that, you can actually send the API request if you are using the Chrome browser (My version: Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

However, you are not allowed to send request if using Edge Chromium. It will always ask you to install the local agent, although it's just a web UI wrapper anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Rapid API extension, It's also simple as postman. You can simply search it on vscode and download it. Then you can add it to the vscode.Your all API test can do within the vscode.

Answer (score -2):

@MasterMind provided a correct answer. **Alternatively, you can try using the Thunder Client Extension in VS Code instead of Postman's Desktop Agent.**

You can find more information about it at this link: https://www.thunderclient.com/.