# Error `Cannot send requests to localhost` using POSTMAN Client

Tags: api, rest, postman

When I try to send a GET/POST request to http://localhost:5000/*xyz*_ locally, it works [on my local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTvOe.png) but when I try to do the same with POSTMAN client, it says me to use Desktop Agent [POSTMAN CLIENT FOR API ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPKUg.png).

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67145332/could-not-send-request-error-in-postman-web-version

Comment: Yes, kind of! but even if I download that desktop agent, I am not able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that postman does not knowledge your local host but this problem will occur when you use the postman web version that you can solve it, by postman agent and you can download it, from here https://dl-agent.pstmn.io/download/latest/win64